Pre-80s sci-fi movie/tv show where children stare into mind-control like devices that they hold
Had a conversation with my relative about a movie/TV show they saw in the late 70s/early 80s. It could potentially be a movie from an earlier period.
They say:
"I was young, I think it was the early 80s, and the movie I’m thinking of was an old sci-fi. The memory I have is the children stared into a handheld device with a circular screen, or it may have been worn around their neck like a necklace. The image they looked at was like lightning bolts on the screen, emitting from the center. They stared at it when not doing anything productive, as sort of mind control."

If the device was rectangular, not circular, I'd say it was called "Cell Phone".
